# Validate response format in NestJs

Tags: nestjs

I want to validate responses in NestJs so they can have strictly formatted.

for example when getting users from the database the password field shouldn't be in the response object.
I could delete the password property in users before sending them but I'm wondering is there any way to validate response object and have them transformed before sending them to the client ?

in this case transform means deleting any extra properties like password automatically by using something like DTO and [class-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-validator) / [class-transformer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-transformer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're wanting to use Nest's [ClassSerializationInterceptor](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization). So long as the object you return from your controller is a class instance decorated with `class-transformer` decorators, the interceptor will run `classToPlain()` on it, and put the result back in plain JSON, stripping anything you tell it to as well.

Comment: I know this is the expected answer but your proposed solution is not **validating** the response object...

Comment: You're right, it's not, but it would be possible to extend the interceptor and use `validate` from `class-validator` to do the validations before serializing the result, and the question, if you read it, was about ensuring that a field wasn't sent back, which serialization takes care of